# Execute mee6 commands using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot using JavaScript and I was wondering if there is a way to execute commands using the bot.

For eg. If want to use a mee6 command `!rank` using my bot, I can't

I tried `message.channel.send()` but it didn't work

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. Most bots ignore messages from bots, and using a user account would be against the Terms Of Service for Discord.

The best bet will be to see if mee6 has an API to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Learn Canvas and Database. You can make a rank card using canvas and get level, xp data from database.

Comment: What if their goal is to get the user's *mee6* rank, not the bot rank??